# SOAP and SSL in PHP

Tags: php, soap, ssl

I've got a problem with SOAP and SSL.

When I create a SOAP client with normal wsdl (http), it runs ok. But when I connect with a SSL wsdl (https) it's got problem.

I tried the same code to connect to the https wsdl at my localhost, it's OK. But  it doesn't work if that code run under my server.

My server is running Centos, PHP 5.3.8. Can you show me how to config PHP to run SOAP with SSL. Below is my current code:

```
<?php
    // where BKTransactionAPI extends SoapClient...
    $bk = new BKTransactionAPI("https://www.baokim.vn/services/transaction_api/init?wsdl");
    $info_topup = new TopupToMerchantRequest();
    $info_topup->card_id = $service;
    $info_topup->pin_field = $pin;
    $info_topup->transaction_id = $transaction_id;
    $result = new TopupToMerchantResponse();
    $result = $bk->DoTopupToMerchant($info_topup);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your code how you are creating client object ?

Comment: `<?
 $bk = new BKTransactionAPI("https://www.baokim.vn/services/transaction_api/init?wsdl"); 
 
 $info_topup = new TopupToMerchantRequest();
 
 $info_topup->card_id = $service;
 $info_topup->pin_field = $pin;
 $info_topup->transaction_id = $transaction_id;

 $result = new TopupToMerchantResponse();
 $result = $bk->DoTopupToMerchant($info_topup);
 
 ?>`

Comment: BKTransactionAPI extends SoapClient

Comment: _"it's got problem."_ => do you expect us to guess which problem? What is happening, what is expected output, what error does soap throw, have you inspected the `__getLast*` outputs, etc...

Comment: umm, my case is pretty special. But, generally, can you show me how to config PHP to run well with SOAP and HTTPS. Thank you.